# FireDAC specific exceptions are not being caught in C++ Builder 11.3

Tags: exception, c++builder, firedac

I'm trying to catch FireDac exceptions in my server app in order to keep it from crashing. However, the catch block is never implemented. As an example, below, I have purposefully commented out qryCustomer->Open() line to force the exception.

```
void __fastcall TCustomerTaskForm::OpenTablesBtnClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    try
    {
//      qryCustomer->Open();
        qryCustomer->First();
        dsCustomers->Enabled=true;
        ResizeGrids();  
    }
    catch (const EFDException &exception)
    {
        Log(exception.Message);
    }
```

I have tried to catch each form of FireDAC exception/error that is documented or I could find.

- EFDDBEngineException
- EFDException
- TFDDBError
- EPgNativeException

None are caught in the try/catch block.

Comment: If you instead `catch (const Exception& exception)` and `Log(exception.ToString())`, what does it say? What exception does the debugger tell you is thrown?

Comment: If a Delphi module throws a given type, and C++ is not catching that type correctly, it usually means there is an RTTI mismatch between Delphi and C++. Probably a bad build, or the wrong lib files were compiled in, etc...

Comment: @Ted, thank you.  If I use "Exception" the program gives the normal "cannot work on a closed dataset" and does the Log().  When I try to catch one of the FireDAC specific errors, however, it does not Log() and the program crashes.  The debugger raises the same error in both cases an EDatabaseError.  
With that said, I wanted to catch those specific exceptions so that I could have an Exception chain in the methods using FD to attempt recovery and for reviewing the logs tracing where bugs are caught, since the program will ultimately be in production on AWS.  
I believe Remy may be correct.

Comment: @Remy Thank you for your "experienced" review and statement.

Comment: @pjackson are you building your C++ project with runtime packages and dynamic rtl enabled or disabled?

Comment: Apologies for the lateness.  They are both enabled at this time?

Comment: @Remy why do you ask?

Comment: By having them enabled, your EXE depends on external BPLs that have to be shipped with your app. That can effect its RTTI if you are not careful. Try disabling them, so everything is in the EXE instead.